# ASP.net DataReader execution technique

Tags: asp.net, datareader

I am a beginner.

I heard that DataReader works on  forward only readonly fashion and at a time it will
read a single record.Suppose when i execute the below code

```
SqlDataReader reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();
gv1.DataSource=reader;
gv.DataBind();
```

How the does the gridview  populate  all records?.As the reader is capable of reading one row per read,I thought only the last row is available for GridView to display.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`BindData` will read data from the reader, one record at a time, populating the GridView as it goes.  The GridView does not maintain a connection to the server by way of the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, the Read() method of the DataReader is called during DataBinding, until it returns false (indicating that there are no more records). As each record is fetched, it is added to the html to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

According to **MSDN**:

> The GridView control can be bound to a
>   data source control (such as
>   SqlDataSource, ObjectDataSource, and
>   so on), as well as any data source
>   that implements the
>   System.Collections.IEnumerable
>   interface (such as
>   System.Data.DataView,
>   System.Collections.ArrayList, or
>   System.Collections.Hashtable). Use one
>   of the following methods to bind the
>   GridView control to the appropriate
>   data source type:

As you can see you are just setting your **SqlDataReader reference** to GridView.DataSource. When you call GridView.DataBind method, GridView reads it by  **while (reader.Read())** and fills the corresponding data.